# VSTO Word & Visual basic: Shape.Left property does not take on assigned value

Tags: vb.net, vsto

I want to place a logo at the top right hand corner at each page in a document. This functionality is already present in a Word add-in that is managed by us. However this feature does not work correctly. The add-in converts the image to a shape and then places this image a fixed distance from the left document corner. This works for documents that are A4 formats, but whenever the orientation or size of the document changes, the logo placement is off.

I have tried numerous strategies to resolve this, but haven't found a method that is satisfactory. My current strategy is to determine the distance between the left page side and the logo dynamically and then make this position relative to the right side of the page by calling the .RelativeHorizontalPosition property and linking it to the right margin area.

Unfortunately interacting with the .Left property of the Shape object has been troublesome. The .Left property does not take on the value I assign it, but takes on a negative value. I have checked the parameter I assign it numerous times. Would anyone know why this is the case and how to resolve it?

**Example Code**

```
Private Sub AddLogos(section As Section, header As HeaderFooter)
    Dim wordApp As Word.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
    Dim pageWidth As Single = section.PageSetup.PageWidth
    Dim imgFilePath As String = "filepath"
    Dim leftDistanceA4 As Single = 11
    Dim logo As Word.Shape

    Try
        If wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveFormat >= 12 Then
            logo = header.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(m_sImageLogo, False, True).ConvertToShape()
        Else 'Word 97-2003 Support
            logo = header.Shapes.AddPicture(imgFilePath, False, True)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Error message.")
    End Try

    Dim distanceFromRightPageEdge = wordApp.CentimetersToPoints(21 - leftDistanceA4)
    Dim distanceFromLeftPageEdge = pageWidth - distanceFromRightPageEdge

    With logo
      .RelativeVerticalPosition = WdRelativeVerticalPosition.wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
      .Left = distanceFromLeftPageEdge
      .RelativeHorizontalPosition = WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionRightMarginArea
    End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the left position to an absolute value, you can make it relative and essentially "right-align" the shape. If you set the RelativeHorizontalPosition and Left properties as shown below, the image will be placed in the top-right corner, and will maintain its relative position to that corner even when the document's format or size is altered.

```
    Const imgpath As String = "[your path]"

    Dim app As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    Dim doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document = app.Documents.Add()
    Dim head As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.HeaderFooter = doc.Sections(1).Headers(1)
    Dim img As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape = head.Shapes.AddPicture(imgpath, False, True)
    With img
        .RelativeHorizontalPosition = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin
        .Left = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdShapePosition.wdShapeRight
    End With
    app.Visible = True

    'dispose references
```

> Edit: If you need more control over positioning than simply anchoring the image to the top-right corner of the page, inline shapes do not inherently possess that. Instead, consider using a borderless table in the header to provide more control over its contents. Once the image is a child of the table, you have access to all the table formatting controls to use on your image:

```
    Const imgpath As String = "[your path]"
    Const imgMarginCM As Integer = 2

    Dim app As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    Dim doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document = app.Documents.Add()
    Dim head As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.HeaderFooter = doc.Sections(1).Headers(1)
    Dim tbl As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table = doc.Tables.Add(head.Range, 1, 1)
    With tbl
        .Borders.Enable = False
        .AutoFitBehavior(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAutoFitBehavior.wdAutoFitWindow)
        .Cell(1, 1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight
        .Cell(1, 1).TopPadding = app.CentimetersToPoints(imgMarginCM)
        .Cell(1, 1).RightPadding = app.CentimetersToPoints(imgMarginCM)
        .Cell(1, 1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imgpath, False, True)
    End With
    app.Visible = True

    'dispose references
```

Of course, if you have other items in the header then you would create a table with multiple cells and adjust the spacing appropriately, but for this example I'm just putting a borderless single-cell table in the header and setting its autofit behavior to fitwindow so that the table will fill the width of the page even when margins or format are changed. Then I just set the top and right padding of the cell with the image, and the behavior you are looking for is achieved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was aware of the following technique, however with this technique I was not able to leave some white space between the shape/logo and the corners of the page. Is there a way to adjust this code, so that the logo will be placed 1 or 2 cm from the top and right hand corners?

Comment: See the edit, inline shapes have a lot of graphic formatting options but not so many layout options. Using a table to hold the shape will give you a lot more control over the layout.